# Tor Fails when I Run Two Scripts Simultaneously

Tags: python, tor

I'm getting the following error message when I try to run two equal scripts at the same time:

```
$ python test_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_1.py", line 23, in <module>
    'ERR file /tmp/tor_error_log',
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/process.py", line 255, in launch_tor_with_config
    return launch_tor(tor_cmd, ['-f', '-'], None, completion_percent, init_msg_handler, timeout, take_ownership, stdin = config_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stem/process.py", line 143, in launch_tor
    raise OSError('Process terminated: %s' % last_problem)
OSError: Process terminated: No, it's still there.  Exiting.
```

Please find the code for both scripts below. Does anybody knows how can I set up Tor in order to run this two equal scripts simultaneously? Thanks in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import stem.process
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
import os

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    config = {
        'SocksPort' : '9150',
        'ControlPort' : '9051',
        'Log' : [
            'NOTICE stdout',
            'ERR file /tmp/tor_error_log',
            ],
    },)

service_args = [
    '--proxy=localhost:9150',
    '--proxy-type=socks5',
    ]

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull, service_args=service_args)
driver.get('https://check.torproject.org')
print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text)
driver.quit()
tor_process.kill()
```

Comment: Is this unrelated to your earlier problem in chat where two processes were trying to bind to the same port?

Comment: It keeps failing even when you use different ports so it seems like that's not the problem

Comment: Googling the exception you got (custom one, thrown by the tor lib) leads here: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14457/how-many-local-concurrent-tor-connections-can-i-run

Comment: I added `'DataDirectory': '~/.tor/custom1'` and set different ports for each script and it keeps returning the same error message: `OSError: Process terminated: No, it's still there.  Exiting.`

Comment: I suspect that you need to have different ports and data directories on every running instance. In any case, [edit] your question with relevant updates instead of adding info in comments.

Comment: This is driving me nuts... Just uploaded it to my server and got this new error message: `File "test_1.py", line 25, in <module> 'DataDirectory': '~/.tor/custom1',` (...) `raise OSError('reached a %i second timeout without success' % timeout)`

Comment: But does it work interactively? Updates like this in comments with no context about what you changed in between doesn't help much. Not that I know any of the tech you're using. I'm just trying to google. Have you considered using tor.SE instead?

Comment: Do you really want to keep launching two different Tor instances?  Why not just run one Tor daemon on the system and have the code use it's SOCKS proxy.  Or are you trying to have multiple daemons running so you can have multiple IPs at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `DataDirectory` setting, there's an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592862/80766).

```
tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    config = {
        'SocksPort': '7001',
        'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
        'StrictNodes': '1',
        'DataDirectory': r'C:\Tor\Data2',
    },
)
```

I tested with the same `SocksPort` but different `DataDirectory` and I'm able to get different Exit Nodes.

Note that your error mostly have to do with the presence of the `lock` file in the data folder. Don't copy that file.